# ValueError: time data '1/1/2016 00:09:55' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python

```
>>> dt = '1/1/2016 00:09:55' # It supposes to be month day year
>>> from datetime import datetime
dtp = datetime.strptime(dt, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File 
ValueError: time data '1/1/2016 00:09:55' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'
```

How to parse this time data? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `%Y` instead

```
dtp = datetime.strptime(dt, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Output

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 9, 55)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `%y` specifier calls for a 2-digit year.

```
>>> datetime.strptime('01/01/16 00:09:17', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 9, 17)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 date = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
```

Gives:

> File "C:\Users\achow\Anaconda3\lib_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
>       tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
>
> File "C:\Users\achow\Anaconda3\lib_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
>       (data_string, format))
>
> ValueError: time data '5/23/2016 17:35' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'

Fix it as follows:

```
date = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```